# Typescript - cannot invoke an expression whose type lack of signature

Tags: typescript

I am very new in typescript..

when Iam trying to invoke this javascript like this in typescript

```
window.location('http://localhost:1773/Repository/NetworkPlan/ExportPng');
```

I got compiler error message like this

`cannot invoke an expression whose type lack of signature`

Can anyone help me why I got this error?

Thanks

Comment: To the googlers of the future: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34443593/1783163) is the solution for the general case.

Comment: @peterh Thank you for your time-traveling comment.

Answer (score 36):

TypeScript is saving you from a slight coding error:

```
window.location.href = 'http://localhost:1773/Repository/NetworkPlan/ExportPng';
```

It isn't a method call, it is a property you set.