# How to fix "TS2349: Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature"

Tags: reactjs, typescript, definitelytyped

The DefinitelyTyped library:

```
declare module "history/lib/createBrowserHistory" 
{
    export default function createBrowserHistory(options?: HistoryModule.HistoryOptions): HistoryModule.History
}
```

gives the compile error in the title when used like this (although it worked in plain old .jsx before converting to .tsx):

```
import React = require('react');
import reactDom = require('react-dom');
import ReactRouter = require('react-router');
import createBrowserHistory = require('history/lib/createBrowserHistory');
import routes = require('app/tools/routes');

export function createReactApp() : void
{
    let history = createBrowserHistory(); // <-- error :(
    reactDom.render
    (
        <ReactRouter.Router history={history}>{routes}</ReactRouter.Router>,
        document.getElementById('app')
    );
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The module you are trying to use is an ES6 module, so you must import it using ES6 syntax:

```
import createBrowserHistory from 'history/lib/createBrowserHistory';
```

Alternatively you can use the legacy `import =` syntax and access the `default` property of the exported object instead for the default export (but you shouldn’t; use the ES6 import!).

Comment: Now this compiles, but in the browser I get the error: **Uncaught TypeError: createBrowserHistory_1.default is not a function**

Comment: Then you’re using/loading the wrong library or wrong library version at runtime, or the d.ts file you are using is wrong.

Comment: Then is there a way to override a definition or module somehow (like CSS frameworks allow)? I don't want to stop referencing this definition file because it works for definitions other than this one, and changing it won't work when I next update my external references.

Comment: You can’t override declarations, but you can merge declarations with the same name together. However, DefinitelyTyped is open source, so why don’t you just submit a pull request with fixes to the definition file? OSS isn’t supposed to be a free lunch—it only works when everyone helps to make it work.

Comment: I've done that for some others. But I don't know how to fix this. I've actually found bugs in almost every DT module I've used. I'm thinking I'll just set all my external libraries to <any> and save myself the hassle.

Answer (score 1):

If you are having issues, it's likely due to that version being compiled by Babel which is incompatible with TypeScript imports.

Instead, try importing it like this:

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';
```